# How to handle document.body being null on IE7 when trying to call appendChild on it

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I am getting error specific to Internet Explorer 7 due to `document.body` being null on that platform.

The error happens when I try to do `document.body.appendChild(i)` in the following code:

```js
function nm_eraseCookie(name) {
    nm_createCookie(name,"",-1)
}
var i = document.createElement('IMG');
i.src = '//e.netmng.com/pixel/?aid=403';
i.width = 1;
i.height = 1;
document.body.appendChild(i);
nm_createCookie('nm_belgacom_bt',
escape('tv1=bun_intvtel;tv2=;tv3=;phone1=hbs_discoveryline;phone2=hbs_classical_line;phone3=;inet1=bun_nettvmob;inet2=hbs_adsl_res_plus;inet3=hbs_adsl_res_go;nm_banner=;nm_popin=hbs_discoveryline;'),183);
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why don't you use a version that isn't minified to debug?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is working. Just modify to null check:

```
if(document.body != null){
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

Pointy's suggestion is good; it may work, but I didn't try.

Answer (score 63):

You could try

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(i);
```

Now that won't do you any good if the code is running in the `<head>`, and running **before** the `<body>` has even been seen by the browser. If you don't want to mess with "onload" handlers, try moving your `<script>` block to the very end of the document instead of the `<head>`.

Comment: Good pointing out running the script in the `<head>`. I kept getting a `Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null` because of this. Moving it to the end of the document fixed it as the '<body>' did not exist when it was running in the head.

Answer (score 5):

You can `appendChild` to `document.body` but not if the document hasn't been loaded. So you should
put everything in:

```
window.onload=function(){
    //your code
}
```

This works or you can make `appendChild` to be dependent on something else like another event for eg.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_body_append

As a matter of fact you can try changing the `innerHTML` of the `document.body` it works...!

Answer (score 2):

In 2019 you can use querySelector for that.

It's supported by most browsers (https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector)

```
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

May also want to use "documentElement":

```
var elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.style = "width:100px;height:100px;position:relative;background:#FF0000;";
document.documentElement.appendChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your script is inside head tag in html file, try to put it inside body tag.
CreateElement while script is inside head tag will give you a null warning

```
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Game</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```