# why this simple snippet of javascript code dosen't work

Tags: javascript

Where am I doing wrong? 
Why this snippet of javascript code dosen't work?

This must be easy, but I just don't know why, I'm really a newbie at this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to make a BUTTON element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction()
{
var bodyel = document.getElementById("body");
var block = document.createElement("div");
block.innerHTML = "whatever";
bodyel.appendChild(block);
};


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<body>` element does not have an "id" attribute at all, let alone one whose value is "body".

You could do this:

```
<body id=body>
```

Or this:

```
var bodyel = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

Or just:

```
var bodyel = document.body;
```

Comment: document.body.. is enough

Comment: Not sure why you reverted my edit. The id attribute should have quotes around it.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli quotes are not required in HTML.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli why, if they're not required? What's the benefit of adding 2 bytes to the size of the page? Remember, people on mobile devices literally pay for those bytes!

Comment: Try adding 2 classes to an element without using quotes. Or any attribute with some kind of special character. Or if you're embedding attributes dynamically via some server-side language. It's a convention that's so widely used that you'd struggle to find many counter-examples.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli you need quotes when you need quotes, and you don't need quotes when you don't. You can't have two "id" values for a single element. Counter-examples are rife.

Comment: So you would write this on your page? `<div id=foo class="bar baz"></div>`?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli yes, of course I would. (Actually I'd use single quotes, but that's a detail.) I'd do it because it's required in order for the "class" attribute to be parsed.

Comment: I also don't include `</li>` or `</option>` or `</p>` tags, because they're not required.

Comment: What about comments? Variables names longer than a single letter?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I strip comments in the build, and minify JavaScript. You realize that bandwidth isn't free, right?

Comment: I should add that if I had build tools to do all that stuff for me, I wouldn't worry about it so much, but quoting attribute values is a pain so I'm really happy to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The body does not need to be called with a id

and if yes you have to add that id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to make a BUTTON element.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
 var bodyel = document.body;
 var block = document.createElement("div");
 block.innerHTML = "whatever";
 bodyel.appendChild(block)
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem

```
var bodyel = document.getElementById("body"); //body is not id
```

You can use

```
getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

or

```
var b = document.body;
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
var bodyel = document.getElementById("body");
```

To the following

```
var bodyel = document.body;
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/Mhske/3/)

You need to change your code a little:-

```
var bodyel = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

Rest will work. Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/Mhske/). Also try looking into [document-body-appendchildi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419733/document-body-appendchildi)