# javascript - create dom element and append to body

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to create a function generating dom element.

```
function dom(tag,attr,inner){
    var tag = document.createElement(tag);
    for (var key in attr) {
        if (attr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            tag.setAttribute(key,attr[key]);
        }
    }
    tag.innerHTML = inner;
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
}
dom('div',{class : 'test',id : 'test'},'hello world');
```

This tag didn't seem to be created because function `dom` output an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null all.js:438
```

How could I make it right? Thank you.

Comment: Is this part of a bigger library where `document` is something else? Do you have a body in the page?

Comment: No. It is not. I also tried appending this tag outside this function but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(document)` inside the function and show the result of it.

Comment: Hi, check this answer - suppose will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419733/document-body-appendchildi

Comment: @putvande I've tried with `console.log(document)`. An it output `#document`.

Comment: So `document` in your case is set to be an element with the ID document. You need to find the code where you override `document` as a variable.

Comment: @putvande I've tried to put `console.log(document)` at the top of all  JS files. And it still output `#document`. ~~

Comment: What is the first and last line of code in the file where you have the above function?

Comment: @putvande Actually, this function is a child function of a constructor `var doms = new function(){  this.dom = function(tag,attr,inner){} }`. I put this constructor in a single file. I call this function at the last line of this file `doms.dom('div',{class : 'test',id : 'test'},'hello world');`

Comment: @putvande I found the error. I defined this function as a `function expression`. And I put this file inside `head` tag where the `body` tag has not been loaded yet. Thanks for your enthusiasm.

Answer (score 0):

Where is all.js? If all.js was in head element, you need to run the code after onload or DOMContentLoaded.

```
// DOMContentLoaded or load
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    dom('div',{class : 'test',id : 'test'},'hello world');
}, false);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UYdLt/)

Answer (score 0):

`class` is a reserved tag, you can't use this as a key.
So, you have take another key for the class and check for it in the loop like this:

```
function dom(tag,attr,inner){
        var el = document.createElement(tag);
        for (var key in attr) {
        if (attr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            el.setAttribute(key,attr[key]);
        }

        if (key=="OtherIdentifierForClass"){
            el.setAttribute("class",attr[key]);
        }
    }
    el.innerHTML = inner;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
}
dom('div',{OtherIdentifierForClass : 'test',id : 'test'},'hello world');
```

Furthermore, don't name you're element "tag", use a more describing name.

[Here is a working example](http://jsbin.com/gekagufu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: I think it is fine to use `class` as an identifier there. Did you get an error on it?

Comment: Actually yes. If this is not the mistake, then maybe reusing "tag" as variable name. Anyway it works as i posted for me. If these aren't the mistakes there must be anything wrong with the rest of the code. See here with class as key: http://jsbin.com/gekagufu/2/edit?html,css,js,output this does not work and gives a warning.