# Knockout app doesn't render in IE8

Tags: knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

I have an application developed in Knockout and it works fine on Chrome, Firefox, IE9+ and Safari. My problem is that it does not render anything in IE8 and it only gives me the following error:
Invalid Argument knockout-3.1.0.js, line 1 character 28524

The application itself is located here: http://www.stpaulhomeproducts.com/selections

I'm using device.js to detect screen size and load the appropriate layout, and I don't know if that is messing with IE8 or knockout.

Could anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: If you use the non-minified version of knockout.js you should get a more meaningful error message.

Comment: AT the moment there is a 404 error for knockout

Comment: I've resolved the 404 error. I am also using knockout.debug but the error still doesn't tell me much. It seems to be in the "try" or "catch" method for bindings.

Comment: knockout support ie6 upwards

Answer (score 0):

**Knockout has nothing to do with it**
You are using some Javascript code which does not run on IE-8.

```
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

throws a exception JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference which causes knockout binding to fail.
As document.body is null for ie-8.

You can use

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild()
```

or some other work arounds for this.
[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419733/document-body-appendchildi)

Comment: I tried your solution but it keeps giving me the same error. I've even removed the need to append the script and am now inserting it using a simple <script> tag, but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give url to modified code ? or paste error here

Comment: This is the url: http://stpaulhomeproducts.com/selections/desktop_index.html
And when I run the debugger in IE8, it only gives me these 2 errors: 
No matched device version
Invalid argument. knockout-3.1.0.debug.js, line 2822 character 17

Comment: Hi when i opened in ie8 it was giving appendchild related error so i was not able to debug further.